# checkbox limiter ( multiple instances )

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Yesterday we were kindly given this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/Ed8jQ/

Esentially it limits number of ticked checkboxes, to pre defined amount before submit button can be used.
In this case we set a limit of 3.

2 Issues, and I have tried to contact the coder, to no avail.

1. we would like to run another instance on the same webpage, whereby we can limit checkbox requirement to 2 ticks, before a user can submit a form.
   So there are two instances of this script on one page, not sure how we can separate them though.
   So one div has the code in the fiddle, and user can ( must ) select 3 checkboxes. etc.
   Another div, has similar code but user can ( must ) select 2 checkboxes ( diff id's )
2. we would like a alert if user tries to click either of the form submit buttons, before the requisite checkboxes have been clicked.

The two divs are either or, divs. meaning user downt have to do the one div, and the other div. But can do either,

Any assistance appreciated.

Ok so for button code we have:

```
<span style="float:right;"><input type="button" class="samplePromo" value="Order" onclick="window.location.href='somelink.php';"></span>
```

CSS for button is:

```
.samplePromo {
    padding: 7px 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color:#9fd106;
    width: 80px;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border:1px solid #444444;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.samplePromo:hover {
    padding: 7px 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color:#ec008c;
    width: 80px;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried addressing your issue #1.

For #2, as I am trying to disable the button before requried number of checkboxes are selected. I don't see a need for the alert. May be, I am missing something.

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/kKGcJ/1/

Comment: Actually you are correct. Our issue is we use pure css to create the button. So have an active state and a hover state. Nothing else, so the button still seems clickable. Perhaps this is the issue we should address , not the case of alerting users. So now I have a new problem lol, making a pure css button appear deselected until the parameters of this issue are met. So unless user has clicked 3 checkboxes or 2 on the other div, make button appear unselectable.
Our button code is as follows:
Please see original question, UPDATED

Comment: Sorted I am such an idiot, I just created samplePromo[disabled] css :)